# Converting a MySQL query, to a routine which takes parameter

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm using VSC++ and MySQL ver.5.2.25 database, I've tested a query In MySQL that is like this:

```
   select Name from test.virus where Name LIKE 'b' '%' ORDER BY Name;
```

It works well and return all Names that starts with 'b',I want to use a routine instead of this query, so that I can call the routine from my program.  I've tried this:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `StartWith`(NewName VarChar(20))
BEGIN
select NameVirus from test.virus 
where NameVirus LIKE "'+NewName+' '%'" ORDER BY NameVirus;
END
```

When I Call the routine in MySQL there is no error, but the result is an empty table, I guess that the problem is with type of argument, Which type should be the "NewName" parameter?
Advanced thanks for any reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your like condition in the example query is flawed.  It should be `'b%'`.

The procedure where clause might need to look like this:

```
where NameVirus LIKE CONCAT(NewName,'%') order by NameVirus
```

Comment: When I call the routine, I use this: "Call test.StartWith("b");"   I expected that it works, I don't want to put 'b' in the routine, I want to pars the argument, would you explain more?